# Can I decompose a query into functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to decompose a complex query into some logical blocks that can be reused;

Is there a way to do something akin to the following in PostgreSQL?

```
create or replace function isGood(myTable myschema.thetable)
returns boolean as $$
begin
    return myTable.state not in ('BAD');
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from myschema.thetable myTable where isGood(myTable) limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isGood(my_row thetable) RETURNS boolean AS $SQL$
    SELECT my_row.state not in ('BAD');
$SQL$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

`LANGUAGE SQL` means the function has to be a valid SQL query (and can therefore [be inlined by the query optimizer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions)) and `IMMUTABLE` means that the function result [will always be the same given the same inputs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) (as opposed to `STABLE` where the result also depends on the contents of a table *outside of the given parameters* and `VOLATILE` where calling the function multiple times has no guarantee that the result will stay the same, like if you make use of with `RANDOM()` or `CURRENT_TIME()`), which enables further optimizations.

Functions can also return collections:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_words(sentence text) RETURNS SETOF text AS $SQL$
    SELECT word FROM regexp_split_to_table(sentence, '\s+') as t(word)
$SQL$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

SELECT split_words('Hello world!');
```

...or even virtual tables, which work mostly like views except they can have parameters:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION word_pairs(sentence text) RETURNS TABLE (word1 text, word2 text) AS $SQL$
    SELECT word, lead(word, 1) OVER () FROM split_words(sentence) as t(word)
$SQL$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

SELECT * from word_pairs('Welcome to Stack Overflow!');
```

Depending on what exactly you intend to do, you might also want to use [views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) or [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).